# Android Bluetooth devices in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

```
pairedDevices=mBluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices
for (d in listOfNotNull(pairedDevices)) {
    blueArray?.add(d._____)
}
```

`blueArray` is an `ArrayList` in which i want to store the string name of available bluetooth devices but - `d.getName()` is not working

What can i do?

Answer (score 0):

`listOfNotNull()` in this case will simply create a list with the sole element of what `getBondedDevices()` returns. You're creating a `List<Set<BluetoothDevice>>` and trying to call `getName()` on the `Set`.

Might want to do something like this instead:

```
for (device in mBluetoothAdapter.bondedDevices) {
    blueArray.add(device.name)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should declare pairedDevice as set of BluetoothDevice then iterate through  the set and add to your array

```
val pairedDevice: Set<BluetoothDevice>? = bluetoothAdapter?.bondedDevices
        if (pairedDevice != null){
            var listDeviceName = arrayListOf<String>()
            try {
                pairedDevice.forEachIndexed { index, device ->
                    listDeviceName.add(index, device.name)
                }catch (e:IndexOutOfBoundsException){
                Log.e("TAG", "indexOutOfBond",e)
            }
```